# How do I select XML elements with attribute "name" of value "lastName" using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a family tree using XML and Javascript (/jquery). I ask for the user to input their name, and then I search the XML file. I split the name into variable firstName and lastName, and then search using a JQuery selector.

As you can see below, even after I've directly set lastName to equal the string "Lawlor", I am not able to select the XML element via the "family[name=lastName] selector (as evidenced by the missing console log, which I've included all the way at the bottom).

A portion of the XML file is below, followed by the code I'm using to select the elements which have a family element in which the "name" attribute is equal to the variable "lastName".

What the frack am I doing wrong?

```
<xml id="familyTree" class="hidden">
<generation0>
    <family name="Lion" surname= "DT" children="4">
        <father>Joe</father>
        <mother>Schmoe Rose</mother>
        <child>Lu</child>
        <child>Bob</child>
        <child>Sam</child>
        <child>Dick</child>
    </family>
    <family name="Lawlor" surname="JR" children="5">
        <father>JK</father>
        <mother>Tulip</mother>
        <child>Holden</child>
        <child>Ewell</child>
        <child>Boo</child>
        <child>Scout</child>
        <child>John</child>
    </family>
           ...

$("input#submitButton").click( function () {
    name  = $("input#txtField")[0].value;
    var firstName = name.split(" ")[0];
    var lastName = "Lawlor";
    console.log("Your last name is '"  + lastName + ",' and your first name is '" + firstName + ".'");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'familyTree.xml',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("family[name=lastName] child:contains(firstName)").each(function() {
                console.log("what the FRACK?!");                    
            })
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrow) {
            alert('Data could not be loaded - ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
})
```

JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
jquery....1.0.js (line 20)
Your last name is 'Lawlor,' and your first name is 'John.'
familyTree.js (line 19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use as `lastName` and `firstName` are variables which holds the value to be searched

```
        $(xml).find("family[name=" + lastName + "] child:contains(" + firstName + ")").each(function() {
            console.log("what the FRACK?!");                    
        })
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oszQDX4xqYSshhLb6ddm?p=preview)

Comment: my goodness! thanks, so much! i noticed that in other lines of code, the selector would be set like [attribute=value], and not [attribute="value"], but i didn't know that i had to do what you did above. is there a name for this kind of abstraction or common error (assuming it is common)?

Comment: i see now. when lastName and firstName are inside the quotes, it's being "read" as a string, but outside of the quotes, it's as a variable. great--thanks again!